# Triggering submit event after change when uploading image on Yii2 framework

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, model-view-controller, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to save an image type file by using jquery to trigger the submit. I encountered an issue where it triggers even when the change event is not done.

View create.php:

```
<?php \yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm::begin([
    'options' => [
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
        'id' => 'dynamic-form'
    ]
]) ?>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
    Select Thumbnail
    <input type="file" id="recipeThumbnail" name="recipe">
</button>

<?php \yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

In this view, i specify the id to call it in the javascipt file.

Js app.js:

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('#recipeThumbnail').change(ev => {
        $(ev.target).closest('form').trigger('submit');
    })
});
```

From my understanding here, the trigger('submit') should only run when there is a change which in this case an image file is selected. However, i suspect the event is triggered and it caused an error of **Attempt to read property "name" on null** from the model below on the line **$this->name = $this->recipe->name;**. My other suspicion would be error in the model but i cant wrap my head around where or how it could be.

Model recipe.php:

```
public function save($runValidaiton = true, $attributeNames = null)
{
    $isInsert = $this->isNewRecord;
    if ($isInsert) {
        $this->recipe_id = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(16);
        $this->name = $this->recipe->name;
    }
    $saved = parent::save($runValidaiton, $attributeNames);
    if (!$saved) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($isInsert) {
        $recipePath = Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/storage/thumbnail/' . $this->recipe_id . '.jpg');
        if (!is_dir(dirname($recipePath))) {
            FileHelper::createDirectory(dirname($recipePath));
        }
        $this->recipe->saveAs($recipePath);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Controller RecipeController.php:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Recipe();

    $model->recipe = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('recipe');
    
    if ($this->request->isPost) {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'recipe_id' => $model->recipe_id]);
        }

    } else {
        $model->loadDefaultValues();
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

I hope i explained this well. Is this error actually caused by the js or something else and any insight on this issue is much appreciated:D

Comment: You wrapped the input in a button so clicking the input will also click the button. Which in turn submits the form. Add `type="button"` to the button to prevent this.

Comment: @ChrisG _"Add type="button" to the button to prevent this."_ - no; fix the _broken_ HTML. Both button and input are "interactive" elements, and as such they are not allowed to be nested into each other. Not sure what the point of the button is supposed to be in the first place here - should probably be a `label` instead.

Comment: This works! I did not think wrapping input in the button would cause this, learned something new. Thank you @ChrisG !

Comment: Oh I see, at first i was trying to avoid using from because i will need to specify the action and method which turns out bad of course. Thanks for the insight @CBroe , will fix it along the development.

Comment: @CBroe True, was short on time and provided a quick and dirty fix only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insights from @ChrisG and @CBroe,

The issue was wrapping the input tag in a button tag which will click both button and input at the same time causing the error. An easy fix would be adding **type="button"** in the button tag.

But this is actually a broken HTML as an interactive element should not be nested into each other. The fix to this would be using form and labels with the button so that it is a decent html.